# Concatenating list item properties

Tags: c#, generics

I'm looking for an elegant way of creating a readable form some property of all items living in a `Generic.List`.

Let me illustrate it by an example. I have a data structure like this:

```
public class InfoItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I would use it in my code:

```
List<InfoItem> data = new List<InfoItem>();
data.Add(new InfoItem() { Name = "Germany", Description = "Describes something" });
data.Add(new InfoItem() { Name = "Japan", Description = "Describes something else" });
data.Add(new InfoItem() { Name = "Austria", Description = "And yet something else" });
```

Now, what I want to get, is a string like "Germany, Japan, Austria". Is there some LINQ or generics magic that would do it better than this primitive loop?

```
string readableNames = "";
foreach (var item in data) {
    readableNames += item.Name + ", ";
}
readableNames = readableNames.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
string readableNames = string.Join(", ", data.Select(i => i.Name));
```

Comment: Assuming v4+ (which I think is a fine assumption) otherwise you'll have to convert to `string[]` instead of `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Thank you, it works nearly perfect! Since it's .Net 3.5, I still have to add `.ToArray()` after the `.Select`.

Comment: No problem. My assumption was wrong after all :), but I see that you took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy

```
var str = String.Join(", ", data.Select(x => x.Name));
```